# Custom autocompletion for zsh function

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I keep several `pyenv` environments in `~/environments`.  I've got this function in my .zshrc:

```bash
actenv() {
    source ~/environments/$1/bin/activate
}
```

Is there a way to tell zsh to autocomplete the function using the directory names in `~/environments`?  I understand `compdef` is a thing and I thought about doing `compdef actenv=ls`.  However, this would work on the contents of my current directory instead of `~/environments`.